# How to post page data to an Action rendering a partial view using ajax?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a partial view called "ContactsFilters" which displays some search filters on which we have a "Filter" button:

```
@model AppName.Mvc.ViewModels.VmContactsFilters

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    function btnFilter_onclick() {

        // the below post, gets received by the action but the form data are not posted.
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ControllerName/ContactsList",
            type: 'POST',
            context: this,
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#ContactsListContainer').html(data);
            }
        });

        return false;
    }

</script>

<fieldset>
        <legend>Filter Contacts</legend>
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Company:</th>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompanyName)</td>
                        <th>First name:</th>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <input id="btnFilter" type="submit" value="Filter" onclick="btnFilter_onclick();" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

<div id="ContactsListContainer"></div>
```

When the button is clicked, it calls the below action by post and loads the result from another partial view called "ContactsList" into the "ContactsListContainer" div on the "ContactsFilters" view:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ContactsList(VmContactsFilters vmContactsFilters)
        {
            var result = db.Contacts.Where(c => c.UserId == vmContactsFilters.UserId).ToList();
            // also filtering on other columns

            return PartialView(result);
        }
```

The problem is that the post data, such as Company Name, UserId, etc, are not posted back.

How to post data back to the server?

I know one possible way is to use "data : {}" but I have over 10 text boxes. I hoped I could just say post and all would have been posted by MVC magic!

I know if I define a form post, it would post the object but in that case I won't be able to populate my div since it will show the new view in a separate page rather than the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no magic here. Still you have several options though:

1. Use form to collect the data, but do the request manually still:

   ```
   $.ajax({
       ...
       data: $("#theForm").serialize(),
       ...
   });

   <form id="theForm">
   ...
   <!-- your markup here -->
   ...
   </form>
   ```
2. Check out [AjaxExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505086%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) class and its [BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method. The solution then might look somewhat like:

   ```
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ContactsList", "ControllerName", new AjaxOptions {/*some options here*/}))
   {
   <!-- markup here -->
   }
   ```

Comment: Interesting, With the first approach, it passes a string so how would you deserialize it on the server? I mean is there any built-in function? Otherwise this approach wouldn't any better. I'll look into your second option suggested.

Comment: @TheLight, about the first option - absolutely right, it does. In fact it produces a query string like `param1=value1&param2=value2`. And here is where ASP.NET MVC magic happens - if your class `VmContactsFilters` has properties `Param1` and `Param2` (or, another approach, your action accepts parameters with names `param1` and `param2`), MVC will be able to parse the string above and create an actual object for you.